# MySQL Selection Date between

Tags: mysql

i have this simple mysql code:

```
 SELECT count(avs_id) as gesamtNat FROM sv_erfassung.erfasst WHERE DATUM between '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-02' and rechtsform = 'natürliche Person';
```

Mysql gives me zero result. But that can not be as you can see below

[image]

But if i trie the following:

```
SELECT count(avs_id) as gesamtNat FROM sv_erfassung.erfasst WHERE DATUM between '2016-04-29' AND '2016-05-02' and rechtsform = 'natürliche Person';
```

MySql shows me 24 results.

So whats the Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't associate time with date try this,

```
SELECT count(avs_id) as gesamtNat FROM sv_erfassung.erfasst WHERE DATUM between '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-02 23:59:59' and rechtsform = 'natürliche Person';
```

Comment: The question is tagged as MYSQL. Your query will work in Sql Server.

Comment: @RahulTripathi Check now above query.

Comment: Thx for all the anwers. But if i trie this one SELECT * FROM sv_erfassung.erfasst where DATUM = now(); than i got also 0 result. the datatyp is datetime, i've create my table with JPA @Entity.

Comment: Yes that looks good but as a good practice you should provide time for both the date range(*which eventually will make your answer similar to mine*)

Answer (score 3):

Try to make your query as:

```
SELECT count(avs_id) as gesamtNat FROM sv_erfassung.erfasst 
WHERE DATUM between '2016-05-01 00:00:00' and '2016-05-01 23:59:00'
and rechtsform = 'natürliche Person';
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any records for your first query.

The records displayed in the screenshot are outside the interval, because: `'2016-05-02 13:04:58' > '2016-05-02'` while your `BETWEEN` clause only matches the records up to `'2016-05-01 23:59:00'`